# Why do ColorSeparate and ColorConvert give slightly different output?

Tags: color, image

Consider the following test code:

```
red = {1, 0, 0};
List @@ ColorConvert[RGBColor @@ red, "XYZ"]
Flatten[ImageData /@ ColorSeparate[Image[{{red}}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"], "XYZ"]]
```

The output from this is as follows:

```
{0.436075, 0.222504, 0.0139322}
{0.436075001955032, 0.222504004836082, 0.0139322001487017}
```

So, while the first conversion appears to use the "exact" transformation matrix (expressed in 6-significant-digit entries) directly, the second seems to do something a bit different.

Although the differences are insignificant for practical applications (on the order of $10^{-9}$), I wonder, what leads to this imprecision in `ColorSeparate`? Does it convert to some intermediate color space before doing the transformation to the target color space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `Image` stores as `Real32`:

```
ImageType[Image[{{red}}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"]]
```

> ```
> "Real32"
> ```

(I believe this change happened in V12.)

We can force 64 bit storage:

```
Flatten[ImageData /@ ColorSeparate[Image[{{red}}, "Real64", ColorSpace -> "RGB"], "XYZ"]] // FullForm
```

> ```
> List[0.436075`,0.222504`,0.0139322`]
> ```

Comment: Confirming your belief: the results are identical in Mathematica 11.2.0, even without your parameters tweak.